# Laravel app not working in Firefox

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, laravel-4

I made an app that works on Chrome and IE but throws a `Controller method not found` on FireFox

this is happing when doing an AJAX request for logging in.
after some debugging, found out that only the AJAX request on the home/landing page arn't working.

someone got a clue what could be the problem?
thanks in advance

Comment: Post some code, you are probably using some sort of ajax-stuff that is not supported in firefox.

Answer (score 0):

Found out the problem was related on how FF handles Javascript, there were 2 problems:

1)
my `event.preventDefault();` didn't got handled correctly because I had `function() { // code }` instead of `function(event){ // code }`

2)
if the request was successfull it didn't had a return value, so I returned true

that's it :)